# Python output complex line with floats colored by value

Tags: python, printing, colors, floating-point, format

This is my first python program and my first asking a question on stack overflow so I apologize if my code is a mess and or if my question is ill-formatted.

I would like to print the same line I'm already printing, but each float should be a different color based on its value. (specifically `>.7` is green, `.7<` is red) What is the best way to do this?

```
oreName=[#string names]

#escape char? I know there has to be a better way than this
#but this is the best ive come up with as the escape char didnt
#work the way I thought it should for '%'
char = '%'

netProfitBroker=[
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]

##code that populates netProfitBroker

def printOutput(array):
  "this prints all of the lines"
  for i in range(0,10):
    print oreName[i]+"=   %.3f \t 5"%(array[0][i])+char+"=%.3f \t10"%(array[1][i])+char+"=%.3f"%(array[2][i])    


print "\nnet profit brokered"
printOutput(netProfitBroker)
```

the output looks a bit like this: (I lost some/all of my whitespace formatting when I copied the output here)

```
net profit brokered

Veldspar   =   0.234     5%=0.340   10%=-0.017
Scordite   =   0.752     5%=0.297   10%=0.259
Pyroxeres  =   0.406     5%=1.612   10%=2.483
Plagioclase=   1.078     5%=0.103   10%=1.780
Omber      =   -7.120    5%=5.416   10%=4.612
Kernite    =   -10.822   5%=15.366  10%=6.626
Jaspet     =   17.772    5%=49.278  10%=62.380
Hemorphite =   -35.431   5%=82.912  10%=141.027
Gneiss     =   8.086     5%=-4638.549   10%=-3610.570
Arkonor    =   349.867   5%=-545.284    10%=-340.298
```

essentially:

```
"ore name=" arrayVal1 "5%="arrayVal2 "10%="arrayVal3
```

All the array vals should be printed out to 3 decimal places.

Comment: You can use the [termcolor](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/termcolor) package.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use ASCII color codes at the beginning of your print to change the color, as an example `'\033[91m'` for RED and `'\033[94m'` for BLUE.

**e.g**

```
if array[0][i] > 7:
   print '\033[94m' + oreName[i]+"=   %.3f \t 5"%(array[0][i])
elif array[0][i] < 7:
   print '\033[91m' + oreName[i]+"=   %.3f \t 5"%(array[0][i])
```

You can read about ASCII escape codes [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

**Edit:** *Added additional example code.*

Here is a list of some common colors you can use:

```
Red = '\033[91m'
Green = '\033[92m'
Blue = '\033[94m'
Cyan = '\033[96m'
White = '\033[97m'
Yellow = '\033[93m'
Magenta = '\033[95m'
Grey = '\033[90m'
Black = '\033[90m'
Default = '\033[99m'
```

Additionally as mentioned in the comment. You can chain these to get different colors on the same line.

```
print '\033[91m' + 'Red' + "\033[99m" + 'Normal' + '\033[94m' + 'Blue
```

You could even do a function.

```
# Store a dictionary of colors.
COLOR = {
    'blue': '\033[94m',
    'default': '\033[99m',
    'grey': '\033[90m',
    'yellow': '\033[93m',
    'black': '\033[90m',
    'cyan': '\033[96m',
    'green': '\033[92m',
    'magenta': '\033[95m',
    'white': '\033[97m',
    'red': '\033[91m'
}


def print_with_color(message, color='red'):
    print(COLOR.get(color.lower(), COLOR['default']) + message)


print_with_color('hello colorful world!', 'magenta')
print_with_color('hello colorful world!', 'blue')
```

Comment: This recolors the entire line. What I was hoping to do was recolor just the floats. Each line has three floats that each need their own color.

Comment: You can simply combine them e.g. `print '\033[91m' + 'Red' + "\033[99m" + 'Normal' + print '\033[94m' + 'Blue`

Comment: Here's a more comprehensive list used in golang https://godoc.org/github.com/whitedevops/colors

Answer (score 0):

for Easy copy-paste after print:

```
for style in range(8):
    for fg in range(30,38):
        s1 = ''
        for bg in range(40,48):
            myform = ';'.join([str(style), str(fg), str(bg)])
            skel = '\x1b[{};{};{}m'.format(myform.split(';')[0],myform.split(';')[1],myform.split(';')[2])
            s1 += f'\x1b[{myform}m {repr(skel)} \x1b[0m'
        print(s1)
    print('\n')
```

This code print multiple pretty lines with different colors. example:
`'\x1b[5;31;40m'  '\x1b[5;31;41m'  '\x1b[5;31;42m'  '\x1b[5;31;43m'` for easy copy-paste to code.
After print add to you code:

```
mycolor = '\x1b[5;35;43m'
rest    = '\x1b[0m'
```

and print for preview:

```
print(f"{mycolor}Hello world!{rest}")
```

for preview:
[Stack attach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGgv3.png)